# MapStruct source and destination property lookup

Tags: mapstruct

I'm in the process of converting from ModelMapper to MapStruct
All going well so far except for the situation when sorting and filtering on lists
If I have a mapping from a domain object to an entity for example:

```
@Mapping(source = "contact.address.line1", target = "contactAddressLine1")
```

and from an api I want to filter or sort on contactAddressLine1 then I would like to look up the source (or target when mapping reversed) so I can add it to a dynamic jpq or sql query.

Is there a way to do this with MapStruct?

With ModelMapper I had the ability to create a typeMap

```
modelMapper.createTypeMap(sourceClass, destinationClass);
```

and later

```
TypeMap<?, ?> typeMap = modelMapper.getTypeMap(sourceClass, destinationClass);
```

I could use this type map to lookup source and destination property mappings and hence determine the correct fields for dynamic sorting and filtering queries

Answer (score 0):

There currently is no way to retrieve the field mapping information from mapstruct. There are several feature requests open on mapstruct's github concerning this issue:

- https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/702 (more generic)
- https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/918 (same issue)